# Convert html to wordpress website with content in wysiwyg editor

Tags: html, wordpress

If I transfer an html website to WordPress (I know how to do this) is it possible to make the transfer so that the content on the pages is editable via a wysiwig editor?

My understanding is that any html pages I add to WordPress wont be editable on the front-end in wysiwig unless they were initially created that way.

Instead you will have multiple pages in html and the only way to edit them will be to edit the html directly?

Comment: Importing html into wordpress' wysiwig is easy, but keeping the layout and formatting is not possible.  Basically you will end up with unformatted text.  You will be able to edit the text and add new formatting, but the old formatting will--by defualt--be lost.

Comment: Also, this is a question more suitable for the wordpress.stackexchange.com site, since it doesn't really deal with programming.

Comment: @vlasits I think he means he's built a website in HTML and is converting it to Wordpress. Not just copying HTML into the WYSIWIG.

Comment: Not sure if this is possible as part of the conversion, but you could certainly use Advanced Custom Fields to specify which sections can be edited in the wysiwig.

Comment: That was my thought. So the only way to take an html website and convert it to WordPress but have each page easily editable on the front end is to manually add the content via a wysiwyg one page at a time? Yes, Sam that is correct.

Comment: Well, there are other ways to do it. I once imported 1000 html pages into a wordpress site by writing a script that converted them into the same XML format that Wordpress uses for its content import/export files.  But it was a lot of work.

Comment: How many pages do you have?

Comment: I think its about 150 pages. The pages are actually individual products that can be purchased and are linked to a cart/payment processor.

Comment: You might try this Wordpress plugin.  It looks like it loops through a directory of html files and creates wordpress "Posts" or "Pages" out of them:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/import-html-pages/

Comment: Also relevant: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites

Comment: Yes this is possible. However, you need the help of a plugin to be able to make each section of your website editable. You need to use Advanced Custom Fields.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/